# Rotate function not working in animation jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, rotation, jquery-animate

I know my rotate function works as you can see in this jsfiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QREMj/3/)

This is the code where it works.

```
AnimateRotate(360, "#box", 0, 1000)


    $("#box").animate({

        top : "300px",
        left : "200px",
        width: "200px",
        height: "200px"

    },1000)
```

But when I use my animation function in a for loop, where it rotates 2 degrees in each loop, it doesn't seem to work.

```
for(x = -100; x<130; x+=2){

    AnimateRotate(2, "#box", 0, 0)

    z+=1;

    y = ((Math.pow(x, 2))/-50)+700

    $("#box").animate({

        top : sh-y + "px",
        left : (x*2)+250 + "px",
        width: (z)*2.5 + "px",
        height: (z)*1.8 + "px"

    },12)

}
```

It only rotates 2 degrees, but since it loops 230 times I'm expecting it to rotate 460 degrees. But it just doesn't.

Does anyone know a way to fix this. To see all my code look at this jsfiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WDTff/19/)

Also, you can ignore the stuff inside the loop, it's not important. what's important is the fact that the function does not work when in a loop.

Thanks for any answers. [All code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WDTff/19/)

Comment: You can't place the animation in a for loop, as the loop finishes right away, and the animation is async.

Comment: Is there any way around this. A different method of rotation maybe?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, why don't you just add more rotation and a duration -> http://jsfiddle.net/WDTff/20/

Comment: I actually can't believe it was that simple. I feel senseless for not trying that. I had the idea that it would rotate a certain amount in each loop. Thanks for that !